# Queue the flash images to hit server one at a time

Tags: javascript, ajax

i m new to ajax so need help ...

I m trying to using ajax to put all javascript flash images in queue and sending to server to get back response in order where my website loads faster than before.
 problem is all the flash are hitting server at a time causing slowing down of loading time
so need to pass in queue how can i do it.please help me out.

thanking all,

Answer (score 0):

Staggering your image loading is a Bad Thing because it makes your site take longer to load.  Allowing your page to load normally is the best way to go; you may want to consider [CSS sprites](http://websitetips.com/articles/css/sprites/) or better optimizing your images so that they take less time to load.  For what it's worth, if you're using JPEGs, typically a quality of 40-50 is sufficient for general image/photo use.